# TypeError: 'function' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

A pretty simple code, but why do I get an error?

```
def sumList(l):
    if l == []:
        return 0
    else:
        return sumList[1:] + [l[0]]
def main():
    l=[3,2,5,3]
    print(sumList(l))

main()
```

Comment: `sumList` is only defined in one place: it's a function. Functions aren't subscriptable. You tried to subscript it. Therefore, you get an error telling you that the function isn't subscriptable. The fix is to not try to subscript the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume you meant to do this:

```
def sumList(l):
    if l == []:
        return 0
    else:
        return sumList(l[1:]) + l[0]
def main():
    l=[3,2,5,3]
    print(sumList(l))

main()
```

You want to apply `[1:]` to `l`, not to `sumList` (`sumList` is a function).

You also need to add `l[0]` (the first number) rather than `[l[0]]` (a list of the first number).

With these changes, the program prints `13`.

I think it's a good idea to avoid mixing `l` and `1` in the same program!

Answer (score 0):

In line 5, you've tried to use the function name as a list.  This doesn't work.  Replace it with the name of the input parameter.

```
def sumList(l):
    if l == []:
        return 0
    else:
        return l[1:] + [l[0]]
```